# HTML5 Video only play on scroll on Desktop

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, autoplay

I'm just using Matthew Hudson's device.js (https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js) for browser detection. I have a html5 video that plays when you scroll and pauses when out of the window view.

I want to run the video function only on desktop devices and leave the default click to play functionality on mobile devices.

```
    //Play video when scrolled to
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($("body").hasClass("desktop")) {
    // Get media - with autoplay disabled (audio or video)
    var media = $('video').not("[autoplay='autoplay']");
    var tolerancePixel = 40;

        function checkMedia(){
            // Get current browser top and bottom
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + tolerancePixel;
            var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - tolerancePixel;

            //if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() - 10) {
            media.each(function(index, el) {
            var yTopMedia = $(this).offset().top;
            var yBottomMedia = $(this).height() + yTopMedia;

            if(scrollTop < yBottomMedia && scrollBottom > yTopMedia){
            $(this).get(0).play();
            } else {
            $(this).get(0).pause();
            }
            });
            //}
        }
        $(document).on('scroll', checkMedia);
    }

});
```

The function doesn't run at all even though the body has the class 'desktop'?

Comment: And if you remove the `if ($("body").hasClass("desktop"))` condition, does it work?

Comment: @JeremyThille - yes. It plays the video but produces a bug on mobile.

Comment: So, the body does not have a "desktop" class at the moment this test is performed. How is this class added?

Comment: @JeremyThille via device.js - https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js

Comment: So that's what I say. Device.js didn't have time to do its job and add the "desktop" class to the body, before the test ran. Try to set a breakpoint just before the `if`, and watch the body tag, I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a "desktop" class at this very moment. The class will come a few ms later.